# Splitting a Flask app into multiple files

Tags: python, flask

I am playing around with flask. My directory structure is like so:

```
|--------flask-test
|----------------app
|-----------------------static
|-----------------------templates
|-----------------------venv
|-----------------------__init__.py
```

The `venv` folder holds my virtual flask installation. My `__init__.py` is like so:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This works with no issues however now I would like to split this into two files `__init__.py` and `main.py`. The `main.py` would be in the same directory as `__init__.py`. So far I have tried:

`__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
import main
```

`main.py`:

```
from app import app
@app.route("/")
    def hello():
        return "Hello World!"
```

However I am getting an error that the module `app` does not exist in `main.py` then I try to run `__init__.py`. What am I doing wrong here? Also where should I put the run method?

Comment: You have a circular import... You can't import main within `__init__`. And put the run method in main, after you establish the routes

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using **Flask blueprints**, you can break up your application in multiple files which can be put back together into a larger application.

Below is a sample application broken into 3 files that demonstrates just that:

- **file1** : define a */hello* route
- **file2** : define a */world* route
- **file3** : main app, acts as a glue by using register_blueprint function to integrate the apps in file1 and file2

**file1:** defines app_file1 with route /hello

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, session,abort

app_file1 = Blueprint('app_file1',__name__)
@app_file1.route("/hello")
def hello():
    return "Hello World from app 1!"
```

**file2:** defines app_file2 with route /world

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, session,abort

app_file2 = Blueprint('app_file2',__name__)
@app_file2.route("/world")
def world():
    return "Hello World from app 2!"
```

**file3:** main app

```
from flask import Flask
from file1 import app_file1
from file2 import app_file2
main_app = Flask(__name__)
main_app.register_blueprint(app_file1)
main_app.register_blueprint(app_file2)
```

**Note**: To simplify things, for this example are kept in a single directory. In a larger application, you would want to further break things into directories/modules. Using modules is extra step allows to only expose the functionality you want public, do extra initialization and avoid circular dependencies.

It is also good practice to have additional folders for things like data access like sqlalchemy models. It's always good to encapsulate files that have common functionality like a payment processing into a module for potential reuse, code clarity and maintenance

If your application has a large amount of views, you may want to have additional subfolders as well

Comment: why do both file1 and file2 use the parameter `app_classifieds`, should they be different? Would file 3 be the `__init__.py`? Also where is the run method?

Comment: Because I pasted from an existing app, you are correct. I will fix answer

Comment: file 3 could be __init__.py or anything you want it to be. It is the code merging all the apps from multiple files into a single app. The principle is the same

Comment: This works great. You also need `app.run()` at the bottom of file3. Would you say this is a better approach than that of http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/packages/? The link I posted uses a separate script outside the main app folder. Something like `run.py`.

Comment: Approaches are not contradicting each other. The big plus of a package is if there are circular imports as mentioned, they can be put in the __init__ file but if there is none of that then it does not really matter. I would say it depends on how large your app is going to be and how interconnected code from multiple files is... for 3 self contained files, keep them all in one directory.

Answer (score 3):

I modified the example a bit, but just want to keep it as simple as possible. Structure looks like this:

```
app/
  __init__.py # empty this time
  main.py
  run.py
```

In run you init the app, load the routes from main and putting app.run into __name__ == '__main__' does the trick - because all the code before gets executed.

```
# in run.py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from main import *


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print app.url_map
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Specify your routes in main.py and import from before starting the app.

```
# in main.py
from run import app

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

Comment: get the error File "__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app import main
ImportError: No module named app